# Software-Center Error

Tags: software-center

Software center does not work for me. How to fix this problem? I cant reinstall, remove, uninstall software center...

And here is a log from terminal.

```
derianfox@hp-dv6:~$ sudo apt-get autoremove [sudo] password for
derianfox:  Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree    
Reading state information... Done 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to
remove and 0 not upgraded. 3 not fully installed or removed. After
this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used. Setting up
gconf2 (3.2.6-0ubuntu2) ... /var/lib/dpkg/info/gconf2.postinst: 81:
/var/lib/dpkg/info/gconf2.postinst: gconf-schemas: not found dpkg:
error processing package gconf2 (--configure):  subprocess installed
post-installation script returned error exit status 127 Setting up
software-center-aptdaemon-plugins (0.1.6build1) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/software-center-aptdaemon-plugins.postinst: 6:
/var/lib/dpkg/info/software-center-aptdaemon-plugins.postinst:
pycompile: not found dpkg: error processing package
software-center-aptdaemon-plugins (--configure):  subprocess installed
post-installation script returned error exit status 127 dpkg:
dependency problems prevent configuration of software-center: 
software-center depends on software-center-aptdaemon-plugins; however:
Package software-center-aptdaemon-plugins is not configured yet. dpkg:
error processing package software-center (--configure):  dependency
problems - leaving unconfigured No apport report written because the
error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
Errors were encountered while processing:  gconf2  software-center-aptdaemon-plugins  software-center 
E:Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Found solution.

```
sudo apt-get -m --reinstall install python python-minimal dh-python
sudo apt-get -f install
```

then:

```
sudo apt-get remove software-center
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install software-center
```